# Export categories with tree structure

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It's common to use ID and parent to store the categories tree. In my case, a knowledge base, in `article` table every record(article) belong to a category(with a field `catid`), in `categories` table every record has a `ID` and `parent` to save the tree structure.

```
article table
id | catid | date | subject | content

categories table
id | name | parent
```

The problem is when export article to csv or excel,

```
id | category | date | subject | content
```

how to keep the whole categories tree, just like when a article belong to son category, I want the category like

```
grandpa/father/son/, or grandpa : father : son
```

then can open the csv in excel, menu -> data -> text to column, seperate by ":", you will get a whole tree category not only current category.

work code sample:

```
    $query = 'SELECT `a`.`id` AS `ID`, concat(CASE WHEN ISNULL(`f`.`name`) THEN "" ELSE concat(`f`.`name`,":") END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(`e`.`name`) THEN "" ELSE concat(`e`.`name`,":") END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(`d`.`name`) THEN "" ELSE concat(`d`.`name`,":") END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(`c`.`name`) THEN "" ELSE concat(`c`.`name`,":") END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(`b`.`name`) THEN "" ELSE `b`.`name` END) AS `Category`, `a`.`subject` AS `Subject`,`a`.`content` AS `Content`,`a`.`dt` AS `Date Created`, 

FROM articles as a
LEFT JOIN categories as b ON a.catid = b.id
LEFT JOIN categories as c ON b.parent = c.id
LEFT JOIN categories as d ON c.parent = d.id
LEFT JOIN categories as e ON d.parent = e.id
LEFT JOIN categories as f ON e.parent = f.id

WHERE (DATE(`dt`) BETWEEN \'' . $date_from . '\' AND \'' . $date_to . '\')  order by id asc';
```

hope it help for others which want to export tree structure fields.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); and check what error does it shows?

Comment: Convert it to php? Convert what?

Comment: If it doesn't show an error, please use `$result = mysql_query($query) or die mysql_error();`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php see the red box ? Mysql_* functions are depreciated. You should use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: If you want to see the code as string in php just `echo $query;`. Thats all...

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\wamp\www\hesk\admin\export2.php on line 82

Comment: I want to use ":" to connect the parent category and child category when export to csv file, but in php there always error with ":', I tried `:`, or ':', or ":", or \':\', none can work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the result after querying the database:

```
$query = 'query code here';

$result = mysql_query($query); 

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
  // do something with that row
}
```

<sup>**Besides, mysql_x functions are deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","YOUR DB USER NAME","YOUR DB PASSWORD");
if(!$conn) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("YOUR DB NAME", $conn);

$result = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['ID'];
  -----
  -----
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: I think the problem is some varable and value have to be transition to make it work in php, like add slash '\' before '''.

Comment: Do not use these functions, since they are deprecated! You don't want to shoot yourself in the lag, just because you're learning something.

Answer (score -1):

I assume, you would like to execute the SQL code in PHP, that you designed in phpMyAdmin - which works well. The most common problems are with the quotes. [Learn about String quotes here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

As I see you use `'` to frame the query code, but you use it inside the query as well. That must have produced an awful series of syntax errors. You may use `"` to frame the query code while setting it to a variable.

If you get nothing, than maybe the SQL command could have executed, but the result was empty. You can test this with the `var_dump()` function. Also check that you have all the error reporting switched on. [Learn about error reporting here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Also, I'd suggest you to examine and use the [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of the `mysql` functions, which would throw you handsome exceptions you could catch and deal with the errors elegantly. The `PDO`
 will also secure your code in some way.